# Progressive Enhancement inside div

Tags: css, html, progressive-enhancement

Anyone know of a way to target a div that will hide/show content based on the size of the div similar to the way media tags work.

Example

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="holder">
    <div class="nav visible-nav"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="holder">
    <div class="nav visible-nav"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper{width:100%;}
.holder{width:50%;float:left;}
.holder{width:50%;float:right;}
```

Using a media tag i can target it like so:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width:1200px){ 
        .visible-nav{
            display:none;
        }
    }
```

Any way I can target the div instead of the entire screen??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A not elegant but possible solution would be to use the same code you used, but calculate on what screen width the `.holder` divs will be small enough to hide the `.visible-nav` divs:

for example, if i wanted to hide them when `.holder` is narrower than 400px, since `.holder` is 50%:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:800px){ 
    .visible-nav{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Another way which is not pure CSS would be to use JS or jQuery to apply the conditions.

Comment: Thats currenly what i have but there are other layouts with different column sizes so its not a good choice. I guess doing it via jQuery is only way I can do it within the contents of a div. Thanks.